# Is there an explanation for Xcode's/Swift's treatment of curly braces in var and let statements?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

<promise>No, I am ***not*** kicking the "inline curly braces versus aligned ones" dead dog.</promise>

In Xcode 7.x, if I start an `if`/`then` block and push the opening curly brace down to the next line (or if I `Alt-[` everything over to column one then `Ctrl-I Re-Indent`), Xcode dutifully obeys what I consider to be one (and my personal choice) of the two standards for placement of the opening brace, to wit:

```
if (condition)
{
    /*blah blah*/
}
else
{
    /*yadda yadda*/
}
```

But... if I do this with var or let, Xcode decides that there needs to be another level of indentation on the open --- but not the close --- brace, to wit:

```
var x: Int
  {
  didSet
  {
    /* handle it*/
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? Is there a reason for this, or should I log it as a bug?

Comment: Before you do a bug report, you might also want to post to the [dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/welcome) and see what they say there.

Comment: You'll see curious behavior with trailing closures, too. And chained functional programming can yield very strange indentation, too, even if you put the opening brace at the end of the prior line.

Comment: That's not a dead dog, it's a bike shed. :)

Answer (score 1):

I asked on the dev forum and was told it's an open bug. Thanks!